# How do I unescape XML special characters in Perl?

Tags: xml, perl, entity, escaping

I'm processing some XML files (specifically `.vcproj` files) in Perl and I want to unescape the special characters. The escaped characters I've encountered so far are:

- `&quot;`
- `&#x0D;`
- `&#x0A;`

Obviously I can do this myself but it seems that there should be a standard (or [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org)) module to do this but a naive search brings up nothing relevant.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`XML::Entities`](http://search.cpan.org/~sixtease/XML-Entities-1.0000/lib/XML/Entities.pm) or the older [`HTML::Entities`](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Parser-3.69/lib/HTML/Entities.pm).  I've only used the latter.

Searching probably would have been easier for you if you'd known that these things are called entities; I hate it when I'm in that position of not knowing the key information that would make a search possible.